# How to add plugins from node_modules to Laravel mix

Tags: jquery, laravel

Here is my code

```
   mix.js([
        'node_modules/chocolat/dist/js/jquery.chocolat.js',
        'node_modules/textcounter/jquery.textcounter.js',
        'node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.js',
        'node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.js',
        'resources/assets/js/jquery.fileuploader.min.js',
        'resources/assets/js/app.js',
    ], 'public/js/all.js', './');
```

And I get error that jQuery is not defined. I have downloaded it, it is 100% there.

Comment: mix will load those in sequence, can you put app.js at top if you required jquery in app.js?

Comment: Then I get $ is not defined. How do I compress all js files I use into one file?

Comment: See the more proper resolution at this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43451509/how-to-install-font-awesome-in-laravel-mix

Answer (score 0):

In the example provided in the github repo you can see how it normally is included. Check this file: `resources\assets\js\bootstrap.js`

You should update your webpack file. You didn't include the vanilla jquery in your array. You should do that as the first item in the array. Also, if you just want to concatinate scripts you should use the `scripts()` method instead of the `js()` method.

Comment: So I should use require in my main js file? And lodash is imported because they need it in code. I just want to compress all js files into one file.

Comment: You didn't include the vanilla jquery in your array. Also, if you just want to concatinate scripts you should use the `scripts()` method instead of the `js()` method. I will update my answer.

Comment: Actually, later I've added jquery on first place but errors persist.

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment on the question, this answer to a similar question demonstrates how to properly call the required scripts from `app.js` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43451509/how-to-install-font-awesome-in-laravel-mix