# Integrating Font Awesome in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, font-awesome, laravel-5.6, laravel-mix

I have a Laravel application. I downloaded an admin_template and integrated it into my app. I use Font Awesome with CDN in my admin-template, and it works no problem.

In the front pages of the application, I can't use Font Awesome. I tried all the way, (downloaded, CDN used, etc.) but no luck. Can anybody help me?

I tried this also https://stackoverflow.com/a/43819770/9145012

I'm using Font Awesome 4.7.

Thanks.

Comment: What does your template file look like in the `<head>` section?

Comment: in head tag there are select 2, bootstrap, jquery ui, alertify and custom css, removed fontawesome because not works

Comment: add <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}"> in head. Make sure font awesome is located in assets/font-awesome/css or change the path accordingly

Comment: php artisan cache:clear and php artisan view:clear might need to be run after adding new js/css at times

Comment: found the problem. * {
    /* font-family: Segoe UI, sans-serif !important; affects font awesome */
} in css. :)

Comment: Use Font Awesome version 5 and follow the steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43451509/how-to-install-font-awesome-in-laravel-mix/49716723#49716723

Answer (score 0):

I use `yarn` add it:

```
yarn add font-awesome
```

modify `app.scss`:

```
@import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';
$fa-font-path: '/fonts/font-awesome';
```

and `webpack.mix.js`:

```
mix.options({
    processCssUrls: false
});
mix.copy('./node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/**', 'public/fonts/font-awesome');
```